# Передача значения JSON из response Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking

Здравствуйте, не могу вернуть значения из принятого JSON, имею следующий код:

```
makeRequest(methodName, parameters: parameters) { response, error in
  if let responseData = response?.objectForKey("response") {
    let json = JSON(responseData)
    for i in 0 ..< json.count {
      let element = User(id: json[i]["user_id"].stringValue, firstName: json[i]["first_name"].stringValue,
        lastName: json[i]["last_name"].stringValue, online: json[i]["hidden"].boolValue)
      resultArray.append(element)
    }
  }
}
return resultArray}

func makeRequest(methodName: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject], complete: (NSDictionary?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {
Alamofire.request(.GET, HTTPSRequestAddress + methodName, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
  switch response.result {
  case .Success(let value): complete(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
  case .Failure(let error): complete(nil, error)
  }
}}
```

после вызова функции `makeRequest` возвращается пустой массив, знаю, что замыкание `responseJSON` исполняется асинхронно, пытался обрабатывать добавление нового элемента в результатирующий массив через `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, но тщетно, подскажите пожалуйста, как получить данные?

Comment: можно код текстом а не картинкой

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko извините, заменил фото текстом

Comment: что у вас в response.data?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko json из по vk api, получаю корректно, в консольке все нормально

Comment: а что в responseData?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko response это полный json, responseData выдергивает из JSON типа [response = {my json}], нормального вида Json, с которым я и работаю, а response.data у меня нет, я ошибся, извиняюсь

Comment: я тогда не понимаю, где у вас теряются данные. если у вас есть все в responseData, тогда вроде все должно работать. json это точно массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика получения и обработки данных была абсолютно неверная, следовало было создать какой-то контейнер для данных с сервера и обновлять их теми данными, которые принимаются в замыкании, в запросе

Answer (score 0):

Массив resultArray внешняя сущность по отношению к кложе и зачем же вы внутри кложи сделали return resultArray?

зачем так же у User столько входных параметром, что мешает передать весь JSON Dictionary как [String:Any] в User.init и инициализировать параметры класса уже внутри. весь ваш for замечательно меняется на map, результирующий массив можно потом записать во внешний параметр - будет красиво и коротко

```
var resultArray:[User]?
makeRequest(methodName, parameters: parameters) { response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        // здесь может быть какая-нибудь обработка ошибки
        return
    }

    if let jsonArray = response?["response"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        resultArray = jsonArray.map(User.init)
    }
}
```

где User.init?(_ json:[String:Any])

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Проблема была даже не столько в том, как разворачивать данные, а в том, как работает передача данных через замыкание. В тот момент, когда я задавал вопрос, я не до конца понимал принцип